# Generic collections in vba?

Tags: vba, generic-collections

Does VBA have Generic collections? I am relatively new to VBA. I see it has dictionary data structure. What are the other collections or data structures that vba have?

Comment: If you are asking about the [C#'s Generic Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) then the answer is **no**. VBA does not support generics at all.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a collections object type.

Where the dictionary has a key-value pair system, collections are a list of values. I generally prefer dictionaries for this type of work since it has a .exists method which I often use. You can also roll your own data structures by using class modules.

You can also use single or multi-dimensional arrays. Range data structures are the main way to interface with Excel sheets. If querying databases then ADODB recordset objects are helpful for that.

I use all of these on a regular basis in the VBA world. I haven't demonstrated syntax here as you are looking for more general guidance.